# What is the logic behind this behavior in union?

Tags: c, structure, unions

I have declared an union with 2 structures and assigned values to each of the elements and then printed them.

```
union data {
    struct s1 {
        int a;
        int b;
    }c;
    struct s2 {
        int d;
        int e;
    }f;
} x;

/* Assignment */
x.c.a=1;
x.f.e=2;
x.c.b=3;
x.f.d=4;

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", x.c.a, x.f.e, x.c.b, x.f.d);
```

It outputs like this -> `4 3 3 4`

But, when I assign the values in the follwing order ->

```
x.c.b=3;
x.f.d=4;
x.c.a=1;
x.f.e=2;
```

It outputs like this -> `1 2 2 1`

What is the logic behind this variation ??

Comment: That's the point of unions. `s1` and `s2` share the same memory.

Comment: What you're doing is undefined behavior. You're only supposed to read the union field which was most recently written.

Comment: @Martin In C++ yes, in C it's OK.

Comment: @Martin Well, it may be, it depends on the implementation. At worst you will get an indeterminate value which will trap.

Comment: @2501, no this is always well defined, the C standard explicitly allows this.

Comment: @JensGustedt Trap values will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501, how could there be a trap value in this case? The types are all `int`.

Comment: @JensGustedt Padding bytes in between members in one struct but not the other.

Comment: @2501, not an issue here either, the two union members share an initial sequence that are in fact the members in their entirety.

Comment: @JensGustedt There may be padding in the structs themselves, specifically in between their members. As the structs are two different types one may have padding and the other many not.

Comment: @2501, no, as I said, the standard guarantees that initial sequences that are composed of elements of the same type can be read interchangeably. this is 6.5.2.3 p6.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks I wasn't aware of that rule. However, C still permits that reading will trap. For example: `union{ int a; int b }s; s.a = 1; int r = s.b;` may trap on an exotic architecture.

Comment: @2501, no, not if it is conforming to the C standard.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yeah, you're right, the footnote: *If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6* mislead me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `union` has enough space to store the largest of its members. In your case, both members are of the same size. The memory layout for `x` is such that it can hold two `int`s.

```
x.c.a=1;    // Sets the value of the first int to 1
x.f.e=2;    // Sets the value of the second int to 2
x.c.b=3;    // Sets the value of the second int to 3
x.f.d=4;    // Sets the value of the first int to 4
```

At the end of those statements, you have `3` in the first `int` and `4` in the second `int`.

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", x.c.a, x.f.e, x.c.b, x.f.d);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int i1 = x.c.a;  // i1 is 4
int i2 = x.c.b;  // i2 is 2

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", i1, i2, i2, i1);
```

Which produces the output `4 3 3 4`.

---

When you use:

```
x.c.b=3;    // Sets the value of the second int to 3 
x.f.d=4;    // Sets the value of the first int to 4
x.c.a=1;    // Sets the value of the first int to 1
x.f.e=2;    // Sets the value of the second int to 2
```

At the end of those statements, you have `1` in the first `int` and `2` in the second `int`.

That explains the second output.

Answer (score 4):

In order to understand what is going on you need to recall that `union` members share the same memory. In your case, there are two members of the `union`: one is called `c`, and the other is called `f`.

Any assignment to members of `c` will change the content of members of `f`, and vice versa. In your case, the structure of both members are identical, the following pairs share the same space:

```
x.c.a / x.f.d
x.c.b / x.f.e
```

Any assignment of one member of the pair leads to the other member of the pair changing its value as well. That is precisely the behavior that you see: both members of each pair have identical values equal to the value from the last assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You might know this already, but `union`s specify multiple views on the same block of data. You happen to be specifying two identical views (a structure of two `int`s).

Your two assignment sequences can therefore be re-written, respectively, as:

```
x.c.a=1;
x.c.b=2;
x.c.b=3;
x.c.a=4;
```

and

```
x.c.b=3;
x.c.a=4;
x.c.a=1;
x.c.b=2;
```

.

In the first case, the last assignments made to `x.c.a` and `x.c.b` are `4` and `3` respectively, so they remain. In the second case, these are `1` and `2`, so they are reflected in the output instead.